# Is the code for the Polygon bridge open-source somewhere?

Tags: solidity, polygon, bridge, polygon-bridge

Does Github store the Solidity code for the Polygon bridge? I can't find the official bridge code anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into this:
https://github.com/maticnetwork/pos-portal

"Smart contracts that powers the PoS (proof-of-stake) based bridge mechanism for Matic Network."

Hope this helps!